# Remove the last character from Variable String

Tags: mysql, query, replace

I have a few variable data in the column "email".

For example:

```
roy2087@gmail.com123
sg123@yahoo.compori
```

How do I get rid of the characters after `.com`?

I used `Replace(email,'.com%',gmail.com)`, however, we cannot use wildcard characters in Replace.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(col) - CHAR_LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '.com', -1) ) ) ;
```

If you want update the strings from a table, chopping off what is on the right of `.com`:

```
UPDATE 
    tableX
SET
    col = SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(col) - CHAR_LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '.com', -1) ) ) 
WHERE
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '.com', -1) <> col ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does mysql have regular expressions?
If so, maybe this points in the right direction

```
select regexp_replace ('roy2087@gmail.com123', '\.com.*','.com') email from dual;
```

works in Oracle, not sure about mysql.